# How to filter webform by custom field "ThirdPartySettings"

Tags: webforms

I've created a new field for all my webforms called "color" inside of settings (this field is only for CMS users)

To create this I used "ThirdPartySettings" like this:
https://codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/webform-settings-entity-adding-custom-fields#comment-1129

It's ok. But now inside of /admin/structure/webform I need to create a filter with this field.

Example: to show all webforms with "color" = "blue" or "color" = "red" you know?

[image]